# Where can I download MINGW API docs?

Tags: api, mingw

I am failed that using command man to find some `MINGW` function like `GetPixel()`,`GetDC()`.
So Where can I download a completed `MINGW API` docs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know MINGW. But these APIs are part of Windows API.  You can find these reference on MSDN Web site.

GetPixel
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx

GetDC
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think it is MFC API on MSDN Web site. I want to find these function in MINGW API and include it.(My compiler is gcc)

Comment: It's the same API. That's the whole purpose of mingw: to provide a minimal gnu environment for developing applications for Windows.